# Using Convolution neural network for semantic image segmentation

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am naive to python and this is my first attempt so please bear with me if my question seems to be too basic.
I would like to use convolutional neural network to perform semantic segmentation to 9 satellite images.
I have so far been successful in importing the images one by one and converting them to grayscale.

I would like to do the following process :

convolution- 16 filters, 3*3 filter size
pooling- 2*2 filter size
output- 4 classes
testing and validation 80:20

any lead on this could be helpful. kindly guide !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code, only the model part:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, MaxPool2D

# Declare your desired things here
num_filter=32
kernel_size=(3,3)
strides=(1,1)
padding="valid"
input_shape=(width,height,channel)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   Conv2D(num_filter, kernel_size, strides=strides, input_shape=input_shape),
   MaxPool2D(),
   Flatten(),
   Dense(4, activation="softmax")
])
```

Here is a useful link: [ConvNet TensorFlow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn)

Comment: Thank you so much! Kindly guide. where can I enter my input images ?

Comment: You can use `model.fit(x_train, y_train...)`, in the link there is also the tutorial.

Comment: If you find my answer is acceptable, consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers